# cli showing unknown sip registration in asterisk

Tags: sip, asterisk, voip

I am using asterisk 11.9.0 everything works fine but cli shows unknown sip registrations with my current code running
my cli output

```
 -- Hungup 'DAHDI/i1/9560790782-2fd2'
[Jun 24 14:55:24] NOTICE[3637]: chan_sip.c:25757 handle_request_register: Registration from '"4001" <sip:4001@182.74.197.19:5060>' failed for '37.8.47.82:22939' - Wrong password
[Jun 24 14:55:25] NOTICE[3637]: chan_sip.c:25757 handle_request_register: Registration from '"3822" <sip:3822@182.74.197.19:5060>' failed for '37.8.47.82:23187' - Wrong password
[Jun 24 14:55:29] NOTICE[3637]: chan_sip.c:25757 handle_request_register: Registration from '"5555" <sip:5555@182.74.197.19:5060>' failed for '37.8.47.82:22848' - Wrong password
```

how can i remove this because my dialplan is taking too much time to execute as compared to the past.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic as it's not programming related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likly that is automated programs(bots) with goal find your secrets/on success call out to Cuba or other costly destinations.

Every asterisk installation need have at least rate limiter - usually fail2ban.org used. That will prevent bots from spamming too fast.